# Understanding Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

> Suppose we may want to use the K–T conditions to find the optimal solution to:
> \begin{array}{cc}
> \max & (\text { or } \min ) z=f\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}\right) \\
> \text { s.t. } & g_{1}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}\right) \leq b_{1} \\
> & g_{2}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}\right) \leq b_{2} \\
> & \vdots \\
> &g_{m}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}\right) \leq b_{m} \\
> & -x_{1} \leq 0 \\
> & -x_{2} \leq 0 \\
> & \vdots \\
> & -x_{n} \leq 0
> \end{array}
> then the theorem state the KT condition as:
> [image]

Which I really don't understand and eventually failed to applied as my book didn't illustrate any example with details. For sake of clarity, let's pick one minimization problem,

\begin{array}{ll}
\text { Minimize } & Z=2 x_{1}+3 x_{2}-x_{1}^{2}-2 x_{2}^{2} \\
\text { subject to } & x_{1}+3 x_{2} \leq 6 \\
& 5 x_{1}+2 x_{2} \leq 10 \\
& x_{1} \geq 0, i=1,2 .
\end{array}

After google searching and watching YouTube video, I find they solve it by,

$$L(x_1,x_2,x_3,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=2 x_{1}+3 x_{2}-x_{1}^{2}-2 x_{2}^{2}+\lambda_1(x_{1}+3 x_{2}-6)+\lambda_2(5 x_{1}+2 x_{2}-10)$$

$(1)$ Assuming both $g_1$ and $g_2$ active:

Solving $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}=0,\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}=0,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_1}=0,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_2}=0 \implies \left(\frac{18}{13},\frac{20}{13},\frac{185}{169},-\frac{11}{169}\right)$ Which can't accept.

$(2)$ Assuming $g_1$ active:

Solving $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}=0,\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}=0,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_1}=0 \implies \left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},1,0\right)$, hence $z=\frac34$

$(3)$ Assuming $g_2$ active:

Solving $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}=0,\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}=0,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_2}=0 \implies \left(\frac{89}{54},\frac{95}{108},0,\frac{7}{27}\right)$, hence $z=\frac{371}{216}$

$(4)$ Assume none of constraint is active:

Solving $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}=0,\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}=0 \implies \left(1,\frac{3}{4}\right)$ hence $z=\frac{17}{8}$

Hence, $z_{\min}=\frac{3}{4}$

---

So, I was confusing how the second method satisfy the theorem $10$? Like did they do the same thing? Checking the inequality is binding or not? And could I write the second method on exam as a solution for KKT condition?

Comment: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eREvLgRJWrE) is the YouTube video link which I mention on the post

Comment: Ok so think of a convex domain in $\mathbb R^2$ whose boundary is given by curves $g_i(x_1,x_2) \leq b_i$. Now think of a possible minima for a function $f$. Where can it be? it can be in the interior of the domain, or maybe it can be in a point in the boundary. However, there are points in the boundary which are corners and others which are only sides. So you subdivide the problem. If the point is in the interior of the domain means that there is "no restriction" active so you just check if it is an extreme point for $f$. In other words, you set $\lambda_j=0$ and try to solve $Df=0$. (+)

Comment: (+) Then you check if one of the restrictions is active so the other ones are irrelevant etc etc. Formally speaking you are basically taking the equalities $\lambda_i(b_i-g_i(x))=0$ and saying ok first suppose $g_i(x) \neq b_i$ so $\lambda_i=0$ and then suppose $g_i(x) = b_i$ but $\lambda$ can be arbitrary. This is the way I used to see this since I really hated optimization and only a geoemtric way of thinking about it helped me

Comment: Sound intuitive but still there are so many conditions mentioned in the theorem $10$, which seems unintuitive, especially condition $36,38$. @AitorIribarLopez. But thanks for your geometric intuition, you can collect your comments and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First try to understand the following simplified version of KKT:

Suppose you are trying to solve the problem

$$\text{min } f(x)$$

$$\text{s.t. } g_j(x) \leq b_j$$

Where (if i don't recall bad, $f$ and the $g_i$ are convex). Then KKT conditions tell you that if $x^*$ is a solution then you can find $\lambda_j$ such that:

1. $\lambda_j \geq 0$ for all $j$
2. $\lambda_j [g_j(x^*)-b_j]=0$ for all $j$
3. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x^*)+ \sum_j \lambda_j \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i}(x^*)=0$ for all $i$ or equivalently $\nabla f + \sum_j \lambda_j \nabla g_j=0$

Note that the sets $g_j(x)=b_j$ form the boundary of your domain. Look at condition 2. It basically says: "either $x^*$ is in the part of the boundary given by $g_j(x^*)=b_j$ or $\lambda_j=0$. When $g_j(x^*)=b_j$ it is said that $g_j$ is **active**. So in this setting, the general strategy is to go through each constraint and consider wether it is active or not.

As you can see, condition 2. is independent of $f$, it is just about the location of $x^*$ in the domain. It is about "how many constraints does $x^*$ hit sharply"?
Note that for example if no $g_j$ is active, then $\lambda_j=0$ for all $j$ and you are looking for solutions to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x^*)=0$ ie extreme points of $f$.

Now suppose there is only one constraint, call it $g$, and suppose it is active. The you have something like this situation:

[image]

(Sorry for handwritten picture but I am so bad at drawing with the computer)

So if $x^*$ is a minimum of $f$ then it means that when you take points $x'$ inside the domain $A$, $f(x')$ is greater than $f(x^*)$. Now, since $g$ is convex, the vector $-\nabla g$ does always point inwards (or paralell), so you would like $f$ to increase in the direction of $\nabla g$. This applies to all points of the border of the boundary $g(x)=0$ so one would think that a minimum must be one where $f$ increases "the most" in the direction of $\nabla g$. Since the direction in which $f$ increases is given by its gradient, you want $\nabla f(x^*)$ and $-\nabla g (x^*)$ to be proportional one to another by a ppositive constant. This exaclty means that there exists some $\lambda \geq 0$ such that $\nabla f = - \lambda \nabla g$. These are precisely conditions 3. and 1., and this reasoning generalizes to more constraints.

(Note that here I am explaining things vaguely. the fact that this works uses strongly that $f$ and $g$ are convex and is precisely is the statement of the Theorem of KKT, whcih is not trivial)

Now, how does this translate to your example? In your example you have two type of restrictions: given by some unknown funtions $g_j$ and other ones given by $-x_i \leq 0$. Let's apply the conditions 1.-3. to the problem
$$\text{min } f(x)$$

$$\text{s.t. } g_j(x) \leq b_j \quad\text{and}\quad -x_j\leq 0 $$

Let's call $h_i$ the function sending $x$ to $-x_i$. We should have multipliers $\lambda_j$ (corresponding to the $g_j$) and $\mu_i$ (corresponding to the constraints $h_i \leq 0$) such that

- (1)$\lambda_j, \mu_i \geq 0$ for all $i,j$.
- (2a) $\lambda_j (g_j(x^*)-b_j)=0$ for all $j$.
- (2b) $\mu_i(h_i(x^*)-0)=0$ or equivalently $\mu_i x_i=0$ for all $i$.
- (3) $\nabla f(x^*) + \sum_j \lambda_j \nabla g(x^*) + \sum_i \mu_i \nabla h_i(x^*)=0$.

But $\nabla h_i = (0,\ldots , -1, \ldots 0)$ so the conditions in (3) actually read as

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x^*)+ \sum_j \lambda_j \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i}(x^*) - \mu_i=0$$

Therefore, regarding your text, (39) and (40) is just (1), (36) is (3), (37) is (2a) and (38) is (2b) after sustitution of $\mu_i = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x^*)+ \sum_j \lambda_j \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i}(x^*)$ into the equation $x_i \mu_i=0$.

The 'method for solving these problems' given in the Youtube video is just setting the conditions to be active or not, which is the same as doing: if $\lambda_j (g_j(x^*)-b_j)=0$ then either $\lambda_j=0$ of $g_i(x^*)=b_j$, except that you don't do the ones for the constraints $\mu_ix_i=0$ because they are easy to handle without making new cases, since you would have to condider $2^4=16$ possibilities...

Comment: great answer! I myself have been trying to understand this lately!

Comment: Nice answer! So, basically things are reverse for maximization, isn't it? There we increase $f$ in the $\nabla g$ direction, hence $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g\implies \nabla f-\lambda\nabla g=0 $ and the rest of the condition might be similar. Thanks, @AitorIribarLopez

Comment: Another thing I want to cross verify is, does sign of $\lambda$ play a role in Lagrange Multiplier method? Like some book use $L(x_1,x_2,\lambda)=f(x_1,x_2)+\lambda(b_i-g_i(x_1,x_2))$, if I use $L(x_1,x_2,\lambda)=f(x_1,x_2)+\lambda(g_i(x_1,x_2)-b_i)$ then got the right solution, but the sign of multiplier is reversed which change the meaning of shadow price and here I am concern @AitorIribarLopez

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory yes, that's the only thing that changes for maximization. The isgn of the $\lambda$ does not matter when one uses Lagrange multipliers, because in that  one looks for extreme points, not necesssarily minima of $f$.